# laravel page expired after being idle for long time

Tags: laravel

I have a website, and users are complaining they got `Page Expired` after being idle and if they refresh the website it is showing `Page Expired`. I tried searching and what I'm seing is `Page Expired` because of the `@csrf` but in my case I think it's not the problem.

It's working fine, but being idle for a long time is resulting in `Page Expired`

How can I prevent this?

```
Laravel version: 7.x
Server: Apache
```

EDIT:

Now I understand, that if the user is idle for a long time, the session is expired and the laravel is logging out the user. But in my logout it is a `POST` method as default of Laravel that's why it's page expired because of the `token` from `@csrf`

Logout:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
   {{ __('Logout') }}
</a>

<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: did you put csrf token in your form?

Comment: yes, it's working fine. but being idle for a long time is resulting in `Page Expired`

Answer (score -1):

**first of all make sure you put csrf_token in your form**

then you can follow:

as much as i know it is ok that laravel does this after being inactive for a long time
it is because some security problem.

but if you dont want it for some routes you can exclude your route (NOT RECOMMENDED DUE TO SECURITY) in :

```
app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:

protected $except = [
    'your/route'
];
```

i didnt do it myself. test it and see it works or not but it should

Comment: well, this may work. but because of security I also don't want to do this.

Comment: yes you shouldnt do this and this is ok to see that message after being inactive

Comment: may I ask what's your session lifetime?

Comment: 'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

Comment: if any answer helped you mark it as the best answer so other can find it in a minute and use the answer